# TemplateDoesNotExist at /wiki/CSS/edit_entry error in djano

Tags: django, django-templates

I have tried other answers in StackOverflow, but didn't find a solution.
I have a function that edits the page content:

```
def edit_entry(request, title):
    content = util.get_entry(title)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            title = form.cleaned_data["title"]
            util.save_entry(title, content)
            return redirect('edit_entry', title)

    return render(request, "encyclopedia/edit_entry", {
        "title": title,
        "content": content
    })
```

My urls.py looks like:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("wiki/<str:title>", views.entry, name="entry"),
    path("search", views.search, name="search"),
    path("add_entry", views.add_entry, name="add_entry"),
    path("wiki/<str:title>/edit_entry", views.edit_entry, name="edit_entry")
]
```

Here is my edit_html template:

```
{% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Edit page
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<form action="{% url 'edit_entry' title %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ title }}
    {{ content }}
    <input type="submit" value="Save Editing">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

As you see, the template exists here:

[image]

But it says **TemplateDoesNotExist at /wiki/CSS/edit_entry**
The template belongs to my application, so, I guess, no need to add it to DIRS = [], which is located in settings.py. And other routes except this one are working fine.

Comment: you missed .html suffix

Comment: @RezaGH, Yeah, missed it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/edit_entry", {
        "title": title,
        "content": content
    })
```

with

```
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/edit_entry.html", {
        "title": title,
        "content": content
    })
```

Your template should have the full file name `edit_entry.html`

Comment: Thank you, this was the only mistake that I couldn't find for many hours :))